# R-Tree vs R+-Tree vs R*-Tree

Tags: r-tree

What would be a major reasons to prefer R+-Tree over R-Tree for a spatial indexing? As I know, R+-Tree avoid nodes overlapping which lead to more complex code, more complex division algorithms and so on. R*-tree is very similar to R-tree, but minimizes node overlapping and require much less code than R+-tree. So, what would be a reason to choose R+-tree over R*-Tree, except the case when each node lookup requires expensive IO?

Answer (score 1):

If you object overlap badly, the R+-tree paritioning may be beneficial, as you have to look at fewer leaves and paths through your tree for searching a particular location.